Regex for extracting different data formats
I was looking into this question, and trying to adapt the same problem. I have to extract all data inserted into a txt file. So far i have reached the following (barely readable) pattern
import re
pattern = r'(?<![A-Za-z0-9-\./])\b(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s.])?(?:(?:Jan|January|Feb|February|Mar|March|Apr|April|May|Jun|June|Jul|July|August|Sep|September|Oct|October|Nov|November|Dec|December)[\s,.]*)?(?:(?:\d{1,2})[-/th|st|nd|rd\s,.]*)?(?:\d{2,4})\b(?![A-Za-z0-9-/])'
dates = df.apply(lambda row: [match for match in re.findall(pattern, row)])

But alongside my text file there are some numbers being catched, for instance 29505 would be catched by the regEx, but I have been unsuccessful in fixing it so that 2,3,5 or more digit numbers are not considered. Any hints on what can I do? Is it easier to drop those on a post filter?

There's no need for the list comprehension. re.findall() returns a list.

What do you mean by "all data inserted into a txt file"? Did you mean all dates?

[-/th|st|nd|rd\s.] doesn't do what you think it does. You need to learn the difference between character sets in [] and grouping with () in regular expressions.

@Barmar yes, all dates.

@Barmar I was assuming it would be any instance of th or st or nd or rd, considering dates formated like 21st or 22nd

The strange thing is that you did it correctly for the list of month names. Why would you think it's different for the ordinal number suffixes?

@Barmar oh you mean the lack of a ?: term?

No, I mean the fact that you used square brackets instead of parentheses, e.g. (th|st|nd|rd)

It looks like you're trying to be too clever by mixing all the formats together. I suggest you write a separate regexp for each date format you want to match. Then you can match any of them by combining with |, i.e. pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|...

Where did you get [-/th|st|nd|rd)\s.] from? When I've been searching for a suitable duplicate for this question, I keep encountering similar bits in the questions and answers. It's like a meme that everyone copies without really considering whether it makes sense.

@Barmar its linked in the question. Oddly it does break the code depending on how you switch it.

Indeed, that was one of the questions I ran into when I was searching for a duplicate. It seems like few of the people answering really examined the regexp.

Try https://regex101.com/r/MLQ7Hj/1

As you mentioned, the "barely readable pattern" can be made readable
by the use of the x flag, to let you use comments and spaces.
Then I would propose a few changes/improvements:

Accept lowercase months by using the i flag.
Check that the day is between 1 and 31.
Be consistent in the list of months (3 chars or full month name).
Make space between day, month and year mandatory (or maybe not, up to you).

I would come up with this pattern:
\b(?<![-./])      # Don't match if the number is preceded by '-', '.' or '/'
# Group 1: Day number, only between 1 and 31, with optional 0 prefix.
(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1])
(?:th|st|[nr]d)?  # Optional st, th, rd, nd
\s+               # space(s) before month.
# Group 2: Month.
(Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|
 June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|
 Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)
\.?\s+            # Optional dot for month abbreviation and space(s).
# Group 3: Year.
(\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)
(?![-/]?\d)       # The year should not be followed by '-', '/' and digits.

Testing it live here: https://regex101.com/r/TmhiNQ/1
And running it in Python: https://www.programiz.com/online-compiler/9Vr7225izGRPx
